# C# How to make VSCode suggest values of same type first?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I am using VScode to write scripts in C# for unity.
It really annoys me that Intellisense suggests based on some random algorithm when it would be much better to suggest based on value types.

In the example below you can see that I am trying to write **isSpawned = true**, but it suggests me a **transform** which is silly because isSpawned is a **bool** and that suggestion will make an error.
[Vscode exaple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4eyN.png)

Is there a way to fix that behaviour?

Comment: it offers `transform` because there is an implicit conversion to [`bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) ..

Comment: @derHugo, thanks a lot for info! So I guess it's impossible to fix this, because VSCode does what it was programmed to do

Answer (score 0):

it offers you 'true' below transform I don't think it's possible to fix that but you can add an extension like tabnine.

Comment: I know it suggests true in the next option, but it really messes up with workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the Tabnine, I tried it now and unfortunately it was not for me. Tabnine is wway too intrusive, it tries to be everywhere and breaks the flow even more with strange suggestions.